# Programmatically set the current home CMS/Page in Magento in PHP

Tags: php, html, magento, content-management-system

I'm looking for a solution in PHP to programmatically set the CMS home page in Magento. What I'm looking for is what you get when you use the manual method of selecting a page title from the dropdown in the System->Configuration->Web->CMS Home Page.

I already have the methods to determine pick any one of the set of Page Titles or I can pick from the Set of URL keys for all the CMS pages in the store.  If I know either the Page Title or the URL Key, what is the PHP Mage methods to needed to change the current CMS home page.

I have already figured the code to create a new CMS Page as well. I'd just like to be able to select it and make it actively the home page when I'm done.

Edit: 02/18/2012

tried the following without success:

```
    $groups['default']['fields']['cms_home_page']['value'] = 'city-grips-handle-bar-covers';

    Mage::getModel('adminhtml/config_data')
        ->setSection('web')
        ->setWebsite('Main Website') 
        ->setStore('My Store Name') // Hid Actual Store name here
        ->setGroups($groups)
        ->save();
```

EDIT: Thanks for the screenshot.  I didn't have those right.  My url when selecting the store is .../index.php/admin/system_config/edit/section/general/website/base/store/default/

Which I assume means website=base, store=default

[image: website store]
<sub>(source: [reefworkshop.com](http://reefworkshop.com/posts/website_store_url.png))</sub>

I changed the code to:

```
    $groups['default']['fields']['cms_home_page']['value'] = 'city-grips-handle-bar-covers';

    Mage::getModel('adminhtml/config_data')
        ->setSection('web')
        ->setWebsite('base') 
        ->setStore('default')
        ->setGroups($groups)
        ->save();
```

But I'm still not showing the CMS Home page selected change.  I refresh the front end and it doesn't switch.  I've also tried clearing cache with no luck.  Any ideas?  just FYI I'm running Magento CE 1.5.1.0

EDIT:

Here's the file contents that I run.  I put the file at the root of my Magento Install.:

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
       <?php      
        require_once('app/Mage.php'); //Path to Magento
        umask(0);
        Mage::app(); // Change default to whatever store you want to run

        print('CMS 1<br>'); 
        $groups['default']['fields']['cms_home_page']['value'] = 'city-grips-handle-bar-covers';

        print('CMS 2<br>'); 
        Mage::getModel('adminhtml/config_data')
            ->setSection('web')
            ->setWebsite('base') // Code is the field name
            ->setStore('default')
            ->setGroups($groups)
            ->save();

        print('CMS 3<br>'); 
        ?>          
     </body>
 </html>
```

When I run it is see in the browser window:

```
CMS 1
CMS 2
CMS 3
```

EDIT: 
OK So I found a solution (that works) that was inspired by the last proposed solution:

```
require_once('app/Mage.php'); //Path to Magento
umask(0);
Mage::app(); // Change default to whatever store you want to run

$Config = new Mage_Core_Model_Config();
$Config ->saveConfig('web/default/cms_home_page', "city-grips-handle-bar-covers");
Mage::app()->cleanCache();
```

Voila it works.  The configuration cache is really all that it needed to be cleaned (I confirmed this manually). So cleaning all the cache is a little overkill but oh well it works.

Comment: Where do you put this code? And do you see anything in the `exception.log`?

Comment: Exception log has some stuff in it.  I don't think its related:  exception 'Mage_Core_Exception' with message 'Invalid block type: checkout_cart' in /chroot/home/babyhalf/babyhalfoff.com/html/app/Mage.php:550  There are 28 layers of stack dump, but I don't think the stimulus is related.  It also repeats, I only ran the CMS page code once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here it is.  This works on the default store and will change the CMS Home Page to whatever you put in .  Obviously a CMS page with this URL must exist.  You'll get an error on the front end if you specify one that does not exist.

```
require_once('app/Mage.php'); //Path to Magento
umask(0);
Mage::app(); // Change default to whatever store you want to run

$Config = new Mage_Core_Model_Config();
$Config ->saveConfig('web/default/cms_home_page', "<URL-Key-goes-here>");
Mage::app()->cleanCache();
```

Answer (score 2):

Try in this way:

```
        $groups['default']['fields']['cms_home_page']['value'] = '<your_cms_page_url_key>';

        Mage::getModel('adminhtml/config_data')
            ->setSection('web')
            ->setWebsite('<your_website_code>')
            ->setStore('<your_store_view_code>')
            ->setGroups($groups)
            ->save();
```

To quickly find out website code and store view code - go to System->Configuration, select needed store view from dropdown at the left and look at page url:

**EDIT:**

Another approach, works only in install script:

```
/** @var $installer Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Mysql4_Setup */

/** @var $store Mage_Core_Model_Store */
$store = Mage::getModel('core/store');
$store->load('<needed_store_code_>');

$installer->setConfigData('web/default/cms_home_page','<your_cms_page_url_key>','stores',$store->getId())
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I've been trying to get it to work without success yet.  I have replaced <your_cms_page_url_key> with the the content of the URL Key field in the CMS page.  (Looks like this-is-my-url-key)  I also replaced <your store website> with the contents of the Website Name field under manage stores. I've replaced <your_store_code> with the contents of the Store Name field under manage stores in the backend.  I even tried the code field for the website name.  It doesn't seem to affect the current CMS page after I run the code and refresh the browswer.

Comment: I also already fixed the typo from your sample code:  $groups['default'].  I know it runs because I have prints in the code after the new code I added.  I see those prints come out in the browser.  Any ideas?  Thanks,  Kyle

Comment: I edited my answer - added screenshot how to quickly find out website and store view codes, hope it helps you.

Comment: Thanks for the extra info.  I was not selecting the website and store values correctly.  I edited my question with my resulting code.  It for some reason still doesn't work.  Any ideas?

Comment: Thanks for all your help on this.  I did learn quite a bit as I researched each of your suggestion.  However, this approach also did not work.  I'm not sure why not, but it did inspire a quick google search which ultimately lead me to a working solution.  I posted it below.