# Change theme based on visitor browser

Tags: magento, magento-1.7, magento-1.9

I'm using a theme that doesn't support old IE versions like 6,7,8,9,10 so I want to change Magento theme(Skin, Layout & default) and default CMS Home Page programmatically if the visitor is using one of the previous browsers and if not the visitor will use the default theme.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<frontend>
    <events>
        <controller_action_layout_load_before>
            <observers>
                <magento_test>
                    <class>magento_test/observer</class>
                    <method>changeLayoutEvent</method>
                </magento_test>
            </observers>
        </controller_action_layout_load_before>
    </events>
</frontend>

public function changeLayoutEvent($observer) {
  if(preg_match('/(?i)msie [1-10]/',$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'])) {
       // if IE<=10
        Mage::getDesign()->setArea('frontend')
        ->setPackageName('default')
        ->setTheme('modern');
    } else {
        // if IE>10
        Mage::getDesign()->setArea('frontend')
        ->setPackageName('mycustompackagename')
        ->setTheme('mycustomtheme');
    } 
 }
```

To change default CMS home page check this: [Programmatically set the current home CMS/Page in Magento in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9324019/programmatically-set-the-current-home-cms-page-in-magento-in-php)

Hope this helps!!

Comment: It is working as a charm but how can I set the default CMS Home Page also?

Comment: have updated the answer. pls accept the answer if it helped

Comment: If I enabled the caching website isn't loading well when I switch between themes as it cache the other theme please advise

Comment: clear cache programmatically after switching theme code.

Comment: This is not a practical solution as each request will clear the cache so it will act as the cache is disabled.

Comment: if u have a better solution feel free to suggest it. besides the cache will only be cleared the first time the theme is set for the user not every single time.